# How I can set-up LXTerminal in Lubuntu to start maximized?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, lubuntu, lxde, lxterminal

When I push <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> I want see my default `LXTerminal` in Lubuntu 13.04 in full size (not like F11). I know that I can push <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and get tty-terminal - it good for some situations, but sometimes I need, for example, copy text from/to terminal.

I found that I can bind in `.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` command `lxterminal --geometry=85x27` - its very good, but sometimes I need configure not one PC with Lubuntu - and all this PC may be with anothers screen resolution. And `lxterminal --geometry=85x27` look little as not good as, like LXTerminal in full screen.

Comment: Try this [Post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46195/how-to-make-lxterminals-open-maximized-in-lubuntu-11-04), see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OBApps](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications) work for me. GUI for edit OpenBox options. [Official page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/obapps/index.php?title=Main_Page).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 12.04:

Inside the applications block in /home/(your username)/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml, add the following block and it will work:

```
<applications>
    <application name="lxterminal">
        <maximized>yes</maximized>
    </application>
</applications>
```

Similarly, if you want to minimize it, use iconic tab and set to "no".

If you want it full screen, there is also the aptly named fullscreen tag you can use exactly as the maximized tag example above.

Comment: Now I am at Xubuntu 14.04 and at `~/.config` I not have folder `openbox`. I need create it?

Comment: You are going to need to install openbox, not just create the folder.  Found this with a quick google search, haven't tried it though as I'm not a Xubuntu user myself:  http://dottech.org/129812/how-to-install-openbox-xubuntu-linux/

Comment: openbox already installed at Xubuntu

Comment: There is not even a predefined hotkey to do that. Yet another proof added to the pile of "LXDE is lightweight because it lacks even basic functionality". Pretty sad...

Comment: The file was ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml for me in Lubuntu 16.04 and 17.10.